# javascript generating invalid HTML5 attributes in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am noticing some very strange behavior in firefox and I'm wondering if anyone has a strategy for how to normalize or work around this behavior.

Specifically if you provide firefox a basic anchor containing html entities it will unescape those entities, fail to re-escape them and hand you back invalid html.

For example firefox mishandles the following url:

`<a href="&gt;&lt;&quot;">My Original Link</a>`

If this url is parsed by firefox it will unescape the `&gt;&lt;&quot;` and start handling a url like:
`<a href="<>"">My Original Link</a>`

This same operation appears to work fine elsewhere, even safari and edge.

I tried quite a few different ways of handing the html to firefox to avoid this problem. Tried manually invoking the parser, tried setting innerHTML, tried jQuery html(), tried giving jQuery constructor a giant string, etc. All methods produced the same broken result.

See a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kamelkev/hfd2b6sn/

I am a little mystified by how broken this handling seems to be. There must be a way to work around this issue, but I can't seem to find a way.

My application is an html manipulation tool, so I typically normalize around issues like this by dropping down to XML and handling the problems there before persisting to a dumb key-value store, but in this particular case the `<>` characters are preventing me from processing this document as XML.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<` or a `>` is valid inside of an attribute value, unescaped.  It's not best practice, but it is valid.

What's happening is that Firefox is parsing the original HTML and making elements out of it.  At that point, the original HTML no longer exists.  When you call `.outerHTML`, the HTML is reconstructed from the element.

Firefox then generates it using a different set of rules than Chrome does.

It isn't clear what exactly you need to do this for... really you should edit the DOM and export the HTML for the whole DOM when done.  Constantly re-interpreting HTML isn't necessary.

Comment: `<` and `>` inside attribute values are valid in HTML, but not in XHTML.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, exactly.  The question is about generating HTML5.  Or at least, that's what the title indicates.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had always thought that it was invalid to use unescaped html markup within an attribute. Since my application is entirely browser based I have an html normalization layer (rewrite attributes such that they are identical across all browsers) that requires a pass through xml before storing. It's at this point that I start running into problems. I can't normalize as html as the browsers won't cooperate. For example IE will consistently rewrite certain styles as shorthand styles rather than retain the original ones provided.

Comment: @kamelkev It still isn't entirely clear to me what you're doing and why.  You're making an WYSIWYG HTML editor of sorts?  Or some sort of other HTML editor?  Why not build and manipulate the DOM, then export the resulting XHTML?

Comment: That is effectively what I do. I build a document in HTML5, which ends up including a large number of browser inconsistencies such as this ```<``` and ```>``` quirk of firefox (turns out IE has it too) and then I export to XML, normalize and persist it. My problem in this particular case was that the ```<``` and ```>``` existing within the document prevented me from processing the document as XML. What I have now done is used a regex to escape these characters, after which my XML parser can handle the document. A regex is obviously not a great idea, but I don't see an alternative.

Comment: @kamelkev Do you want HTML5, or do you want XHTML?  And, can you elaborate on the "normalize" step?

Answer (score 1):

The `&gt;` and `&lt;` are unescaped when the parser parses the source to construct the DOM. When you serialize an element back to a string, you are not guaranteed to obtain the same text as the source.

In this case, [`innerHTML`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML) and [`outerHTML`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-outerHTML) use the [HTML fragment serialization algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#html-fragment-serialization-algorithm), which [escapes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#escapingString) attribute values using attribute mode:

> Escaping a string (for the purposes of the algorithm above) consists
>   of running the following steps:
>
> 1. Replace any occurrence of the "`&`" character by the string "`&amp;`".
> 2. Replace any occurrences of the U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE character by the string "`&nbsp;`".
> 3. If the algorithm was invoked in the *attribute mode*, replace any occurrences of the """ character by the string "`&quot;`".
> 4. If the algorithm was *not* invoked in the *attribute mode*, replace any occurrences of the "`<`" character by the string "`&lt;`", and any
>      occurrences of the "`>`" character by the string "`&gt;`".

That's why `"` is escaped to `&quot;`, but `<` and `>` remain.

This is OK, because `<` and `>` are allowed in [HTML double-quoted attribute values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-(double-quoted)-state):

> - U+0022 QUOTATION MARK ("): Switch to the [after attribute value (quoted) state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#after-attribute-value-(quoted)-state).
> - U+0026 AMPERSAND (&): Switch to the [character reference in attribute value state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-in-attribute-value-state) [...]
> - U+0000 NULL: [Parse error](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error) [...]
> - EOF: [Parse error](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error) [...]
> - Anything else: Append the [current input character](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#current-input-character) to the current attribute's value.

However, XML does not allow `<` and `>` in attribute values. If you want to get valid XHTML, use a XML serializer:

```js
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString(document.querySelector('a'));
console.log(str);
```

```html
<a href="&gt;&lt;&quot;">My Original Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer. The other guy answered slightly sooner though. I have upvoted your answer as it's definitely going to be useful to others.